How to replace parentheses within parentheses with square brackets in Microsoft Word?
I have a bunch of citations in my documents that are within parentheses, like:

(Susan Schreiner, Are You Alone Wise? The Search for Certainty in the Early Modern Era (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2011), 79–130)

The parentheses within parentheses should be replaced with square brackets, like so:

(Susan Schreiner, Are You Alone Wise? The Search for Certainty in the Early Modern Era [Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2011], 79–130)

Is there a way to do this automatically using wildcards and find and replace or a macro?

See code by robbarrett at https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/7311/how-to-get-parentheses-to-change-to-brackets-when-citation-is-in-parentheses

You can try the following:

Press Ctrl+H to open the Find and Replace window
Find what: (\(*)\((*)\)(*\))
Replace with: \1[\2]\3
Search options: Select Use wildcards
Press Replace All



Here is a VBA solution. The code targets the string "(Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2011)" specifically as the OP requested. This should be less prone to errors than the all wildcard solution. Other format strings could be easily coped with. The year is targeted using wildcards for four digits. See the extensive comments for exact details. The solution is based on the questions as in the links referenced.
Option Explicit

' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370529/word-vba-range-find-always-starts-at-zero-regardless-of-the-vale-in-range-start
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.wrap
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401859/word-vba-findtext-pattern-with-an-optional-character-find-method

Sub sbReplaceCitationBrackets()
'
'                           1         2         3         4         5
'                  12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
' Early Modern Era (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2011), 79-180).
'                 1^-----------------------------------39^
'                    this is the target string to find
'
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
'
'                             1         2         3         4         5
'                    12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
            .Text = "\(Oxford: Oxford University Press, [0-9]{1,4}\)"
'                   1^ escape character
'                    2^ round bracket at the start of the target string
'                     3^-----------------------------35^ the literal part of the string to find
'                                                     36^------45^ wildcard sequence to match four digits - "year"
'                                                               46^ escape character
'                                                                47^ round bracket at the end of the target string
'
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
        End With
        Do While .Find.Found
            .Select
            Select Case MsgBox("Replace this one?", vbYesNoCancel)
            Case vbCancel
                Exit Sub
            Case vbYes
                .Characters(1).Text = "["
                .Characters(39).Text = "]"
            Case Else
            End Select
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Find.Execute
        Loop
    End With
    MsgBox "Done..."
End Sub

